# How to change the starting point of a branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Usually I create a branch by running a command like `git checkout -b [branch-name] [starting-branch]`. In one case, I forgot to include the `starting-branch`, and now I want to correct it. How do I do so after the branch has already been created?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The short answer is that once you have some commits, you want to `git rebase` them, using the long form of `git rebase`: `git rebase --onto newbase upstream`.  To find out how to identify each of these, see the (very) long answer below.  (Unfortunately, it got a bit out of hand and I do not have time to shorten it.)

The problem you have here is that in Git, branches don't *have* a "starting point"—at least, not in any useful way.

#### The term "branch", in Git, is ambiguous

The first issue here is that, in Git, the word "branch" has at least two distinct meanings.  Usually, when we talk loosely about "the branch", it's clear from context whether we mean the branch *name*—the thing that's a word like `master` or `develop` or `feature-X`—or the thing that I call "branch ancestry" or "branch structure", or more informally, a "DAGlet".<sup>1</sup>  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

In this particular case, unfortunately, you mean both of these, at the same time.

---

<sup>1</sup>The term DAG is short for Directed Acyclic Graph, which is what the commit graph is: a set of vertices or nodes, and directional (from child to parent) edges, such that there are no cycles through the directed edges from any node back to itself.  To this I simply add the ["-let" diminutive suffix](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/let_3).  The resulting word has a happy resemblance to the word [aglet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aglet), plus a certain [assonance](http://literarydevices.net/assonance/) with the word "dagger", making it sound slightly dangerous: ["Is this a DAGlet which I see before me?"](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/macbeth/page_50.html)

#### Draw your commit graph

Whenever you need to grapple with these issues, it helps to draw a graph of what you have now, or at least some useful subset of what you have now.  There are of course many ways to draw this (see that linked question for several options, including some bad ones :-) ), but in plain text in a StackOverflow answer, I generally draw them like this:

```
...--o--o--o           <-- master
         \
          o--o--o--o   <-- develop
```

The round `o` nodes represent *commits*, and the branch names `master` and `develop` point to one specific *tip* commit on each branch.

In Git, every commit points back to its parent commit(s), and this is how Git forms branch structures.  By "branch structures", I mean here particular subsets of the overall ancestry part of the graph, or what I call the DAGlets.  The name `master` points to the tip-most commit of the `master` branch, and that commit points back (leftward) to another commit that is the previous commit on the branch, and that commit points leftward again, and so on.

When we need to talk about specific commits within this graph, we can use their actual names, which are the big ugly 40-character hashes that identify each Git object.  Those are really clumsy though, so what I do here is replace the little round `o`s with uppercase letters:

```
...--A--B--C           <-- master
         \
          D--E--F--G   <-- develop
```

and now it's easy to say, e.g., that the name `master` points to commit `C`, and `C` points to `B`, and `B` points to `A`, which points back to more history that we don't really care about and hence just left as `...`.

#### Where does a branch begin?

Now, it's perfectly obvious, to you and me, based on this graph drawing, that branch `develop`, whose tip commit is `G`, starts at commit `D`.  But it's not obvious to Git—and if we draw the same graph a little differently, it may be less obvious to you and me too.  For instance, look at this drawing:

```
          o             <-- X
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- Y
```

Obviously branch `X` has just the one commit and the main line is `Y`, right?  But let's put some letters in:

```
          C             <-- X
         /
...--A--B--D--E--F--G   <-- Y
```

and then move `Y` down a line:

```
          C            <-- X
         /
...--A--B
         \
          D--E--F--G   <-- Y
```

and then look what happens if we move `C` down to the main line, and realize that `X` is `master` and `Y` is `develop`?  Which branch *is* commit `B` on after all?

#### In Git, commits may be on *many* branches simultaneously; DAGlets are up to you

Git's answer to this dilemma is that commits `A` and `B` are on *both* branches.  The beginning of branch `X` is way off to the left, in the `...` part.  ***But so is the beginning of branch `Y`.***  As far as Git is concerned, a branch "starts" at whatever root commit(s) it can find in the graph.

This is important to keep in mind in general.  Git has no real concept of where a branch "started", so we wind up having to give it extra information.  Sometimes that information is implied, and sometimes it is explicit.  It's also important, in general, to remember that commits are often on *many* branches—so instead of specifying branches, we usually specify commits.

We just often use branch names to do this.  But if we give Git just a branch name, and tell it to find all the ancestors of the tip commit of that branch, Git goes all the way back in history.

In your case, if you write the name `develop` and ask Git to select that commit *and its ancestors*, you get commits `D-E-F-G` (which you wanted) *and* commit `B`, *and* commit `A`, and so on (which you didn't).  **The trick, then, is to somehow identify which commits you *don't* want, along with which commits you do.**

#### Normally we use the two-dot `X..Y` syntax

With most Git commands, when we want to select some particular DAGlet, we use the two-dot syntax described in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), such as `master..develop`.  Most<sup>2</sup> Git commands that work on multiple commits treat this as: "Select all commits starting from the tip of the `develop` branch, but then subtract from that set, the set of all commits starting from the tip of the `master` branch."  Look back at our graph drawing of `master` and `develop`: this says "do take commits starting from `G` and working backwards"—which gets us *too many*, since it includes commits `B` and `A` and earlier—"but *exclude* commits starting from `C` and working backwards."  It's that *exclude* part that gets us what we want.

Hence, writing `master..develop` is how we name commits `D-E-F-G`, and have Git compute that automatically for us, without having to first sit down and draw out a big chunk of the graph.

---

<sup>2</sup>Two notable exceptions are `git rebase`, which is in its own section just below, and `git diff`.  The `git diff` command treats `X..Y` as simply meaning `X Y`, i.e., it effectively just ignores the two dots entirely.  Note that this has a very different effect than set subtraction: in our case, `git diff master..develop` simply diffs the tree for commit `C` against the tree for commit `G`, even though `master..develop` never has commit `C` in the first set.

In other words, mathematically speaking, `master..develop` is normally `ancestors(develop) - ancestors(master)`, where the `ancestors` function includes the specified commit, i.e., is testing ≤ rather than just <.  Note that `ancestors(develop)` does not include commit `C` at all.  The set subtraction operation simply ignores the presence of `C` in the set `ancestors(master)`.  But when you feed this to `git diff`, it *does not* ignore `C`: it does not diff, say, `B` against `G`.  While that might be a reasonable thing to do, `git diff` instead steals the *three*-dot `master...develop` syntax to accomplish this.

#### Git's `rebase` is a little bit special

The `rebase` command is almost always used to move<sup>3</sup> one of these DAGlet commit-subsets from one point in the graph to another.  In fact, that's what rebase is, or was originally anyway, defined to do.  (Now it has a fancy *interactive* rebase mode, which does this and a bunch more history editing operations.  Mercurial has a similar command, `hg histedit`, with a slightly better name, and much tighter default semantics.<sup>4</sup>)

Since we always (or almost always) want to move a DAGlet, `git rebase` builds in this subset selection for us.  And, since we always (or almost always) want to move the DAGlet to come just after the tip of some *other* branch, `git rebase` defaults to choosing the target (or `--onto`) commit using a branch name, and then uses that same branch name in the `X..Y` syntax.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>3</sup>Technically, `git rebase` actually *copies* commits, rather than moving them.  It has to, because commits are *immutable*, like all Git's internal objects.  The true name, the SHA-1 hash, of a commit is a checksum of the bits making up the commit, so any time you change anything—including something as simple as the parent ID—you have to make a *new*, slightly-different, commit.

<sup>4</sup>In Mercurial, quite unlike Git, branches really *do* have starting points, and—more important for `histedit`—commits record their *phase*: secret, draft, or published.  History editing readily applies to secret or draft-phase commits, and not so much to published commits.  This is true of Git as well, but since Git has no concept of commit phases, Git's rebase must use these other techniques.

<sup>5</sup>Technically the `<upstream>` and `--onto` arguments can just be raw commit IDs.  Note that `1234567..develop` works just fine as a range selector, and you can rebase `--onto 1234567` to place the new commits after commit `1234567`.  The only place that `git rebase` truly needs a branch *name* is for the name of the current branch, which it normally just reads from `HEAD` anyway.  However, we usually *want* to use a name, so that's how I describe it all here.

---

That is, if we're currently on branch `develop`, and in this situation that we drew before:

```
...--A--B--C           <-- master
         \
          D--E--F--G   <-- develop
```

we probably just want to move the `D-E-F-G` chain onto the tip of `master`, to get this:

```
...--A--B--C              <-- master
            \
             D'-E'-F'-G'  <-- develop
```

(The reason I changed the names from `D-E-F-G` to `D'-E'-F'-G'` is that rebase is forced to *copy* the original commits, rather than actually moving them.  The new copies are just as good as the originals, and we can use the same single letter name, but we should at least note, however vaguely, that these are in fact copies.  That's what the "prime" marks, the `'` characters, are for.)

Because this is what we usually want, `git rebase` will do this automatically if we just name the *other* branch.  That is, we're on `develop` now:

```
$ git checkout develop
```

and we want to rebase commits that are on branch `develop` and are *not* on `master`, moving them to the tip of `master`.  We might express this as `git somecmd master..develop master`, but then we would have to type the word `master` twice (such a dreadful fate).  So instead, Git's `rebase` infers this when we just type in:

```
$ git rebase master
```

The name `master` becomes the left side of the two-dot `..` DAGlet selector, and the name `master` *also* becomes the target of the rebase; and Git then rebases `D-E-F-G` onto `C`.  Git gets our branch's *name*, `develop`, by reading out the current branch name.  In fact, it uses a shortcut, which is that when you need the current branch name, you can normally just write `HEAD` instead.  So `master..develop` and `master..HEAD` mean the same thing, because `HEAD` *is* `develop`.

**Git's `rebase` calls this name the `<upstream>`.**  That is, when we say `git rebase master`, Git claims, in the documentation, that `master` is the `<upstream>` argument to `git rebase`.  The rebase command then operates on commits in `<upstream>..HEAD`, copying them after whatever commit is in `<upstream>`.

This is going to become a problem for us soon, but for now, just make note of it.

(Rebase also has the sneaky, but desirable, side feature of omitting any of the `D-E-F-G` commits that sufficiently resembles commit `C`.  For our purposes we can ignore this.)

## What's wrong with the other answer to this question

In case the other answer gets deleted, or becomes one of several other answers, I'll summarize it here as "use `git branch -f` to move the branch label."  The flaw in the other answer—and, perhaps more importantly, precisely *when* it's a problem—becomes obvious once we draw our graph DAGlets.

#### Branch names are unique, but tip commits are not necessarily so

Let's take a look at what happens when you run `git checkout -b newbranch starting-point`.  This asks Git to root around in the current graph for the given starting-point, and make the new branch label point to that specific commit.  (I know I said above that branches don't *have* a starting point.  This is still mostly true: we're giving the `git checkout` command a starting point *now*, but Git is about to set it and then, crucially, *forget* it.)  Let's say that `starting-point` is another branch name, and let's draw a whole bunch of branches:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

Since we have four branch *names*, we have four branch *tips*: four branch-tip commits, identified by the names `brA` through `brD`.  We pick one and make a new branch name `newbranch` that points to the *same commit* as one of these four.  I have arbitrarily picked `brA` here:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA, newbranch
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

We now have five names, and five ... er, four? ... well, *some* tip commits.  The tricky bit is that `brA` and `newbranch` both point to *the same* tip commit.

Git knows—because `git checkout` sets it—that we're now on `newbranch`.  Specifically Git writes the name `newbranch` into `HEAD`.  We can make our drawing a bit more accurate by adding this information:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA, HEAD -> newbranch
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

At this point, the four commits that used to be only on branch `brA` are now on both `brA` and `newbranch`.  And, by the same token, Git no longer knows that `newbranch` starts at the tip of `brA`.  As far as Git is concerned, both `brA` and `newbranch` contain those four commits and all the earlier ones too, and both of them "start" way back in time somewhere.

#### When we make new commits, the *current name* moves

Since we're on branch `newbranch`, if we make a new commit now, the new commit's parent will be the old tip commit, and Git will adjust the branch name `newbranch` to point to the new commit:

```
                     o   <-- HEAD -> newbranch
                    /
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

Note that none of the other labels moved: the four "old" branches stay put, only the current (`HEAD`) branch changes.  It changes to accommodate the new commit we just made.

Note that Git continues to have no idea that branch `newbranch` "started" at `brA`.  It's just the case, now, that `newbranch` contains one commit that `brA` does not, plus the four commits that they both contain, plus all those earlier commits.

#### What `git branch -f does`

Using `git branch -f` lets us *move a branch label*.  Let's say, for whatever mysterious reason, we don't want branch label `brB` to point where it does in our current drawing.  Instead, we want it to point to the same commit as `brC`.  We can use `git branch -f` to *change* the place to which `brB` points, i.e., to move the label:

```
$ git branch -f brB brC

                     o   <-- HEAD -> newbranch
                    /
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    [abandoned]
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC, brB
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

This makes Git "forget" or "abandon" those three commits that were only on `brB` before.  That's probably a bad idea—why *did* we decide to do this strange thing?—so we probably want to put `brB` back.

#### Reflogs

Fortunately, "abandoned" commits are normally remembered in what Git calls *reflogs*.  Reflogs use an extended syntax, `name@{selector}`.  The *selector* part is usually either a number or date, such as `brB@{1}` or `brB@{yesterday}`.  Every time Git updates a branch name to point to some commit, it writes a reflog entry for that branch, with the pointed-to commit's ID, a time-stamp, and an optional message.  Run `git reflog brB` to see these.  The `git branch -f` command wrote the new target as `brB@{0}`, bumping up all the old numbers, so now `brB@{1}` names the *previous* tip commit.  So:

```
$ git branch -f brB 'brB@{1}'
    # you may not need the quotes, 'brB@{...}' --
    # I need them in my shell, otherwise the shell
    # eats the braces.  Some shells do, some don't.
```

will put it back (and also renumber all the numbers again: each update replaces the old `@{0}` and makes it `@{1}`, and `@{1}` becomes `@{2}`, and so on).

Anyway, suppose that we do our `git checkout -b newbranch` while we're on `brC`, and fail to mention `brA`.  That is, we start with:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- HEAD -> brC
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

and run `git checkout -b newbranch`.  Then we get this:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC, HEAD -> newbranch
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

If we *meant* to make `newbranch` point to commit `brA`, we can in fact do that right now, with `git branch -f`.  But let's say we make a new commit before realizing that we made `newbranch` start at the wrong point.  Let's draw it in:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             o--o--o     <-- brC
                 \  \
                 |   o   <-- HEAD -> newbranch
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

If we use `git branch -f` now, we'll abandon—lose—the commit we just made.  What we want instead is to rebase it, onto the commit that branch `brA` points-to.

#### A simple `git rebase` copies too much

What if, instead of using `git branch -f`, we use `git rebase brA`?  Let's analyze this using—what else—our DAGlets.  We start with the above drawing above, with the extended leg going out to `brD`, though in the end we get to ignore that leg, and with the section going to `brB`, most of which we also get to ignore.  What we don't get to ignore is all that stuff in the middle, that we get by tracing the lines back.

The `git rebase` command, in this form, will use `brA..newbranch` to pick commits to copy.  So, starting with the whole DAGlet, let's mark (with `*`) all the commits that are on (or contained in) `newbranch`:

```
          o--o--o--o     <-- brA
         /
...--*--*--*--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             *--*--*     <-- brC
                 \  \
                 |   *   <-- HEAD -> newbranch
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

Now, let's un-mark (with `x`) all the commits that are on (or contained in) `brA`:

```
          x--x--x--x     <-- brA
         /
...--x--x--*--o--o--o    <-- brB
            \
             *--*--*     <-- brC
                 \  \
                 |   *   <-- HEAD -> newbranch
                 \
                  o--o   <-- brD
```

Whatever remains—all the `*` commits—are the ones that `git rebase` will copy.  ***That's way too many!***

We need to get `git rebase` to copy just the one commit.  What this means is that for the `<upstream>` argument, we need to give `git rebase` the name `brC`.<sup>6</sup>  That way, Git will use `brC..HEAD` to select the commits to copy, which will be just the one commit we need to copy.

But—alas!—now we have a big problem, because `git rebase` wants to copy the commit to a point right after the `<upstream>` we just gave it.  That is, it wants to copy the commits to just after `brC`.  That's where the commits are now!  (Well, the one commit is.)  So this is no good at all!

Fortunately, `git rebase` has an escape hatch, specifically the `--onto` argument.  I mentioned this several times before, but now is when we need it.  We want the copies to go right after `brA`, so that's what we will supply as the `--onto` argument.  Git's `rebase` uses the `<upstream>` *by default*, but if we give it an `--onto`, it uses that instead.  So:

```
$ git branch   # just checking...
  brA
  brB
  brC
  brD
  master
* newbranch
```

OK, good, we're still on `newbranch`.  (Note that `git status` works here too, and if you use one of those fancy shell prompt setup things, you can even get your current branch name to be in your prompt, so that you don't need to run `git status` as often.)

```
$ git rebase --onto brA brC
```

Now Git will select commits in `brC..HEAD`, which is the right set of commits to copy, and copy them right after the tip of `brA`, which is the right place to copy them *to*.  Once the copies are all done, Git will abandon the original commits<sup>7</sup> and make the name `newbranch` point to the new, tip-most, copied commit.

Note that this works even if you have *no* new commits on the new branch.  This is the one case where `git branch -f` *also* works.  When there are no commits, this `git rebase` carefully copies all zero of them :-) and then makes the name, `newbranch`, point to the same commit as `brA`.  Hence `git branch -f` is not always wrong; but `git rebase` is always right—albeit somewhat clumsy: you must identify both the `<upstream>` and the `--onto` points manually.

---

<sup>6</sup>Or, as we noted in an earlier footnote, we can give `git rebase` the ID of the commit to which the name `brC` points.  Either way, we have to supply this as the `upstream` argument.

<sup>7</sup>Except, of course, reflog entry `newbranch@{1}` will remember the old, now-abandoned, tip commit.  Additional reflog entries for `newbranch` may remember yet more commits, and remembering the tip commit suffices to keep all its ancestors alive.  The reflog entries eventually expire—after 30 days for some cases, and 90 for others, by default—but this gives you up to a month or so, by default, to recover from mistakes.

Comment: In your last code snippet `git rebase --onto brA brC` do you mean `git rebase --onto brA brC..HEAD`?

Comment: Can this result in merge conflict since we are now basing from a different branch?

Comment: To the first comment: no, because `git rebase` insists on inserting the `..HEAD` part itself (so you can't, and should not attempt to, supply it).  To the second comment: yes, any time you try to copy commits (with `git rebase`, `git diff | git apply`, `git format-patch | git am`, `git cherry-pick`, and even `git revert`—revert just "backwards applies" after all), you can get merge conflicts.

Comment: Follow-up question: how to rebase onto a commit in the same branch?
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322034/git-how-to-rebase-a-branch-on-top-of-a-commit-in-the-same-branch

Comment: @Attilio: rebase works by commits, not by branch names. Pick the target commit with `--onto` and the upstream-limiter with the other argument as usual. At the end of the copying process, Git moves the *current* branch name to the last-copied-commit (or the `--onto` target if no commits were copied).

Comment: Fantastic reply, thank you! You have put dots on my 'i's that were missing from a long time ago!

Comment: IMO this great reply shows why git interface is poorly designed. In contrast, Mercurial defines the concepts of a "branch" and a "bookmark", with much more intuitive and predictable semantics.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have commits in the new branch, using a `git reset --hard` is the easier.

If you have commits in the new branch...

If your branch start on an older commit that you want to, just do a `git rebase`.

If, more unlikely, your branch start on a newer commit or on a completely different branch, use a `git rebase --onto`

Answer (score -3):

You want the branch to point to a different commit. You can do that by running

```
git branch -f <branch-name> <starting-branch>
```

Note that if `branch-name` is the current branch, you have to switch to a different branch first, for example with `git checkout master`.

Comment: I did this and lost all the changes I made on my branch. Any ideas on how to undo>

Comment: Use `git branch -f` again to put it back.  Use the branch's reflog to find the particular commit at which to point it.  See also the answer I am starting on :-)