# Git: how to rebase a branch on top of a commit in the same branch?

Tags: git

Referencing [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38430972/3398271), which I read and (I think) I understood, but as far as I see does not answer my specific question (because it explains how to rebase onto a commit in a *different* branch, but I want to rebase on the same branch).

**Situation**

- There are two branches, `master` and `feature`, `feature` at some point gets rebased on top of `master`
- Later, for whatever reason* we want `feature` to "branch out" from one of the previous commits of `master`

(* *EDIT:* reason, e.g.: changes in the local `feature` branch broke, after rebasing it on to `master`, so try to find out, which commit on `master` broke the `feature` branch, in a similar way as `git-bisect`)

**Question:** How to achieve this?

**Illustration**

How to go from this:

```
                 G--H--I--J    <-- feature
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F               <-- master
```

...to this?

```
        G--H--I--J             <-- feature
       /
A--B--C--D--E--F               <-- master
```

**Attempts so far**

Attempt #1:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase C
```

Result: `Current branch bug/8985-miniredis is up to date.` Nothing changed.
I think this result is quite logical, because for git, `C` is also part of the "current branch". (Although, from my point of view, the "current branch" is only `G..J`)

Attempt #2:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto C feature
```

Result: `First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...`. And then `feature` simply points to `C` and the other commits are "lost". I don't really understand what is going on here, but again, git cannot know that `feature` "starts" at `F`, from my point of view.

Attempt #3:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto C master..feature
```

Result: `fatal: invalid upstream 'master..feature'`

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427050/how-to-change-the-starting-point-of-a-branch#comment64301034_38430972) of that answer, this is not possible, because `git` inserts the `..HEAD` part itself. But surely, there must be some way to achieve this?

**Question in other words:**

How to achieve what `git rebase --onto C master..feature` would do if it was valid?

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain what is your issue?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you are trying to do ... and it makes absolutely no sense .. what is that "whatever" reason? I mean you can create a new branch, branching from C and then push all your commits there and then delete the old feature branch ... but you will have to deal with merge conflicts surely. But just pulling the branch back to another previous commit will not work. Maybe one of this solutions may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810348/setting-git-parent-pointer-to-a-different-parent or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981052/how-to-re-parent-in-git

Comment: Could you expand on why it "makes absolutely no sense"? Reason I'm doing this (will edit question): e.g. I have a bunch of local commits which stopped working after I rebased them onto master; now I want to find out, which commit from master broke them (a-la `git-bisect`). Re.: "You can create a branch... and delete the old branch": well this is the manual alternative for the normal rebase operation too, no? Actually *1.a* of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4982356/3398271) seems to be exactly what I need; I'll try it and if that is the case, this question can be closed as a dupe

Comment: @phd: yes, see my own answer below, based on the first answer of that question :)

Comment: Now you can remove your question as it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, thanks to @YesThatIsMyName for pointing me to the right direction.

Point 1.a. of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4982356/3398271) has what I need.

Using the notation from above, the right command is the following:

`git rebase --onto C master feature`